# What did I do to set off a siren at the automated e-passport gates in Heathrow arrivals?

Tags: passports, airports, borders

Earlier today as I put my passport in an automated e-passport gate on the way back into the UK at Heathrow Terminal 3, a siren went off (!). What could that mean?

- Did I make a mistake using the machine - standing in the wrong place, or pushing my passport against the scanner too hard? (The lady overseeing the machines had told me to take my glasses off before I went in, so I didn't really know what I was doing.)
- Or did the machine think I didn't match my passport? I'd have thought they'd do that more discreetly.
- Or could it mean I've been flagged somehow and they want to see me in person? Ditto I'd expect more discretion.

Embarrassingly on the way out of the UK last week I had forgotten about a 500ml (sealed, untouched) bottle of diet coke in my hand luggage that got caught by the bag scanner. Would they have recorded my passport number then, and could this be the fall-out from that?

I was sent around the corner to see an actual person, who looked at my passport, asked where I'd flown from, then let me through without any more hassle.

Comment: _The system, which was then on trial at Manchester Airport, would allow two people inside the booths without triggering an alarm_. http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/7908260/Automatic-gates-allow-banned-criminal-into-Britain.html I believe your question though interesting could have many _possible_ reasons and lend itself to conjecture.

Comment: There's probably all kinds of reasons for the system to divert a traveler to a manual check, ranging from a hold on the passport number, to the facial-recognition software being confused and not reaching a positive match (to the degree of certainty configured for it), to not being sure there is only one person in the booth, to _deliberate randomness_ (to keep border guards on their toes and make sure being diverted is not in itself a black mark). It's probable that the floor staff doesn't even know what's behind any given alarm, unless it's a passport flag.

Comment: Did the bag scanner last week even hve access to your passport number to be able to record it anywhere?

Comment: @phoog Not directly, no, unless the machine(s) read the electronic chip from it (it was in the same tray as the bag). But it would be possible via CCTV & computer vision to track me back to the point I showed my boarding card on the way into security, and I think I went past a camera there too. I was really asking if they do. On one hand I'd think they'd want to track if e.g. I make a habit of tripping the bag scanner; on the other hand they wouldn't want to have that capability in case e.g. someone accused them of archiving/leaking millimeter wave scanner images with the subject's identity.

Comment: The electronic chip in the passport is encrypted. It cannot be read without the key, which comprises data from the machine readable zone. So the passport has to be opened and then either scanned optically or read by a human before the RFID chip can be read. Facial recognition is perhaps more plausible, but the number of people forgetting that they have drinks in their bags must be truly huge, and flagging people for that would be an ineffective use of resources.

Comment: Why are you concerned about this?

Comment: @JonathanReez Curious, mostly - I've never seen one sound a siren before, let alone have anything like this happen to me. Nor could I find anything searching (although I didn't think to search for 'alarm' not 'siren'.) And if someone was going to say it's definitely related to the liquid in hand luggage (though sounds like they won't) then I'm interested how long it will follow me around.

Comment: @JonathanReez If you were asking because you want to close this as not-definitely-answerable then fine by me, the comments I've had are probably as close as we'll get and have been interesting.

Comment: This seems answerable to me. Even though we can't know why this particular traveller received a siren, it seems plausible that somebody would know a list of reasons that cause a siren to sound. I don't recall any siren when I was sent for manual contro (the facial recognition couldn't cope with my glasses and I'm short-sighted enough that I couldn't see what it was telling me to do, without them).

Comment: @DavidRicherby agreed. Let's keep this open.